# Experiencing gulp difficulties and learning gulp

Tags: npm, sass, terminal, gulp, babeljs

I have some difficulties with gulp creating a running webpage, my default and scssTask are failing. I input 'gulp' in my terminal on VSCode and it is showing that my functions are starting but then 'scssTask' errored after 481ms and 'default' errored after 484 ms.

```
// Initialize modules
const { src, dest, watch, series } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const terser = require('gulp-terser');
const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Use dart-sass for @use
//sass.compiler = require('dart-sass');

// Sass Task
function scssTask() {
  return src('app/scss/style.scss', { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
    .pipe(dest('dist', { sourcemaps: '.' }));
}

// JavaScript Task
function jsTask() {
  return src('app/js/script.js', { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(babel({ presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] }))
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(dest('dist', { sourcemaps: '.' }));
}

// Browsersync
function browserSyncServe(cb) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: '.',
    },
    notify: {
      styles: {
        top: 'auto',
        bottom: '0',
      },
    },
  });
  cb();
}
function browserSyncReload(cb) {
  browsersync.reload();
  cb();
}

// Watch Task
function watchTask() {
  watch('.html', browserSyncReload);
  watch(
    ['app/scss/**/.scss', 'app/*/.js'],
    series(scssTask, jsTask, browserSyncReload)
  );
}

// Default Gulp Task
exports.default = series(scssTask, jsTask, browserSyncServe, watchTask);

// Build Gulp Task
exports.build = series(scssTask, jsTask);
```

Ive tried looking up some stuff and I am not finding any solutions, i have a feeling that what im trying to do has deprecated in the way im doing it. I have also put the error message through ChatGPT and its telling me to change some of my functions entirely. I am just expecting for the terminal to show up a webpage

Comment: I prefer not to use postcss, I rather use sass-comiler & auto prefixer & and css-minifier
for demo => https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate